# Avoid posting/consuming duplicate messages to/from RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

My requirement is not to consume the messages by the consumer if the condition not met, post the consumed message back to rabbitmq and stop the Masstransit bus (I believe consumer can't be stopped). I can post the consumed message back to rabbitmq and stop the bus but the problem is, as soon as I post the message back, my consumer consumes the same message again before stopping the bus and post the same message back again and it repeats until bus is stopped. In result, I'm getting duplicate messages on the queue.

```
if(!valid)
{
   await ep.Send(message);
   bus.StopAsync();
}
```

I think enabling rabbitmq_message_deduplication plugin may help in this situation but just wonder if there is any other ways to achieve.

Comment: So, generally, posting messages back to the same queue is a good way to consume a lot of resources doing nothing. A better question might be what you're trying to accomplish, instead of how you're trying to accomplish it (which in your example above is a bad solution all around).

Comment: @ChrisPatterson, If a client doesn't have an access, I don't want the messages to be processed by the consumer until they get the access. The message can be sent by a number of users from the client account, consumer should not consume any of those messages as they dont have access. At the same time no message should be lost from the queue and those will be processed once they get the access. Any better solutions?

Comment: you might look at using [scheduled redelivery](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#redelivery) to avoid immediate consumption and to defer the messages for a long period of time (think minutes here) to give time for the client to have access.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Unfortunately Scheduled Redelivery wont work in our case and decided to choose a different approach by modifying application design.